# Update failed because it contains a derived or constant field

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

There is my view from SQL Server Management Studio, column Pocket is set to 0 as default

```
SELECT ToolAssembly.ID, CAST(0 AS int) AS Pocket FROM dbo.ToolAssembly
```

And when I am trying to update the view in MMSD with the code:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [mmlTooling].[dbo].vHHPocket SET Pocket = @pid Where ID = @tid", sqlCon);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", pid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tid", tid);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Then, the error message appeared:

> Update or insert of view or function 'mmlTooling.dbo.vHHPocket' failed
>   because it contains a derived or constant field.

What could be the causes of this problem and how to address it?

Comment: The `Pocket` column in your view isn't a persisted column in your database, what would you expect to happen if it allowed you to update it?

Comment: Also, it's a completely pointless column to return. It's just a constant `0`. Oh, and while I'm here, why cast an int to an int? :)

Comment: Thanks you for the reply.  Is there a way to create view that is updateable and have one column from table ToolAssembly and a column Pocket with 0 as the default value?

Answer (score 4):

`CAST(0 AS int) AS Pocket` is a "derived or constant field".  If `Pocket` is a constant 0, and you tell it to update that value, where are you expecting the database to write that value?

Just update `dbo.ToolAssembly` instead.

Comment: The problem is that dbo.ToolAssembly is a table in database.  I can not update that.  I selected the ID column from dbo.ToolAssembly and a column of Pocket with default value 0 and created a view.  I only wanted to update the Pocket number from the view i just created.

Comment: If you don't have permissions to update `ToolAssembly`, you certainly won't have permissions to update a view based on it, even if you made it updatable.  And 0 is not a default value, it is a constant value -- big difference.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  In that case, is there a way to create a column with a default value?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server views are only updatable under certain conditions. 
Please have a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Check for "Updatable Views" section in the link.

> The update is not working because your view don't fullfil these
>   conditions/restrictions.